# Best way to pass a multidimensional array to PHP to save to database?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, database, json

I am working on an in-browser image layout GUI. The user uploads a series of images to the page, arranges them on the page using jQuery UI Draggable and Resizable, and then saves the position/size of the images using a submit button.

I am getting the final image data like so:

```
$('div.ui-wrapper').each( function(id) {
    var _width = $(this).css("width");
    var _height = $(this).css("height");
    var _left = $(this).css("left");
    var _top = $(this).css("top");
    var _src = $('img').eq(id).attr("src");
    var imgs = {
        'imageID' : id,
        'width' : _width,
        'height' : _height,
        'left' : _left,
        'top' : _top,
        'src' : _src
    };
    finalimgarray.push(imgs);
});
```

I would like the user to be able to submit this array via a form POST to a PHP function which would iterate over each value and store it to a SQL table. What is the best way to do this? I have considered converting to JSON or using a multidimensional array in the post but am not sure how to process an array of data.

Comment: Define criterias for `best` term? Have you tried to implement anything that just works?

Comment: This will be effective if I have data for one image, since it will mimic the pervious array: `<input type="hidden" name="imgdata[imageID]" id="imgdataID" value=""/>` But if I have x amount of images depending on upload, how can I keep adding to the array so it is double nested like so `imgdata[imgID][imgwidth]`, etc recursively with jQuery? Right now I just set the val of a hidden input with jQuery to the `finalimgarray` from above code encoded to JSON, but that results in a messed up encode when passed to PHP with all kinds of extra `/`. Thank you for your help.